# Illustrator CC Radar graph tool - cannot override calculated values

Tags: adobe-illustrator, chart-design

I am using Adobe Illustrator CC on a Mac Pro and trying to modify a radar graph.

I have created a radar graph with two sets of values plotted (two columns of data in the data table, and one column with category labels)

The graph has plotted correctly, but low values are clustered at the centre.

I have tried to improve the readability of the graph by overriding the calculated values for the value axis - starting the axis at -30 to push the low values further out towards the circumference of the radar plot (see image below).

[image: Graph type dialogue box]

When I do this, it has no impact on the graph.  In fact, nothing I do in this dialogue box has any impact on the graph (eg. adding "%" as a label suffix).

I have managed to work around this by changing the graph to a line chart, overriding the values for the line chart and changing it back to a radar chart. When I do this, the manual value axis settings I have entered for the line chart are retained in the radar chart.

Is this a bug in Illustrator?  Has anyone else encountered this issue?